# Cannot Import flask on Raspberry Pi 3 using Python 2.7

Tags: raspbian

I am trying to run flask using python 2.7 on a Raspberry Pi3 but I cannot seem to be able to accomplish this.

Steps that were taken already:

1. Installed flask using:

   `pip install Flask`
2. After trying to import flask with:

   `from flask import Flask`

I got back:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Flask
```

So, I tried to install it using:

`sudo apt-get install python-flask`

after I have uninstalled with `sudo apt autoremove python-Flask`

but still, no luck as I get the same exact error when trying to import flask.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you name your file flask.py?

Comment: I setup Flask as required without me changing any name of any file.
My own file (the one I am using to import flask) has another name...

Comment: Michael, if you want people to know you're responded, it's a good idea to use something like @ben_nuttall to let them know. Do you get the same error with python3? Try from a clean start shell interpreter instead. Also, can you give us the full error, from the line you enter 'from flask import Flask' to the end. Also what happens if you just do 'import flask'?

Comment: It's a common mistake to name your flle the same as what you're importing, and this is the error you get when you do that. It doesn't have to be the file you're running, it could be another file in the same location, or even a folder called `flask` in the same location.

Comment: @ben_nuttall 
I am not having the same name.

Comment: @Τ.Μ. Sorry, I haven't used this platform many times to be acquainted with its rules. Thanks for the reminder. I haven't tried python3 because I am using a sensor for which I have found a way to use only on Python2. It doesn't seem to work on Python3... Furthermore, according to flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/installation/#python-version "We recommend using the latest version of Python 3. Flask supports Python 3.4 and newer, Python 2.7, and PyPy." Although Pyhton3 is recommended, Pyhton 2.7 is not excluded.
I'll post the whole error when I get back to my lab and get my raspberry at hand.